# Want to ask a question that is technically a duplicate but not really

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Rabbi David Bar Chayim recently released a video in which he says that the minor fasts are optional, depending on if one personally feels persecuted or not. You can watch the video, in which he provides all his sources here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FqKkbN0HwQ

So i wanted to ask a question regarding this issue, but we already have a question regarding whether or not minor fasts are obligatory here: [Are minor fasts obligatory?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/are-minor-fasts-obligatory)

But the answer doesn't seem to address the sources Rabbi Bar Chayim provides. So should i ask a new question regarding specifically the sources of Bar Chayim, or should i use Bar Chayims sources to provide an answer that the minor fasts are not obligatory?

Comment: I haven't watched the video; does he say what sources he uses?  Is your question "what sources support this position?" or "according to these sources, are they really optional?" (i.e. checking his reasoning)?

Comment: Why woudn't you just post an answer to the existing question?

Comment: His sources are the Gemara, Rambam, and the Geonim. i haven't checked the sources yet, but if they are what he says they are, i find his argument compelling. But it's also likely that more recent Rabbeim have ruled against the sources he provides, and i wouldn't know how to find out about those

Comment: @IsaacMoses because i don't know enough about the subject. i guess i could post something like "according to Rabbi so and so, using sources x, y, and z, the fasts are optional." Would that be okay?

Comment: @Aaron In that case, it's not a duplicate. You're asking for a refutation of a specific argument rather than the more general question "Are the minor fasts optional?"

Comment: @Aaron, answers don't have to each cover the gamut of relevant opinions. An answer along the lines you've outlined sounds perfectly appropriate.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3507/759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a refutation of his arguments, then I think it makes sense to present them in a question post and ask for a refutation. (Probably, present each of his arguments — the ones you want refutations for — in a separate question post.)

If you're just seeking to impart his wisdom, then it seems to make the most sense to present it as an answer to the preexisting question if indeed it answers that.